# MutableState containing TextFieldValue(text='', selection=TextRange(0, 0), composition=null) cannot be saved using the current SaveableStateRegistry

Tags: android, textfield, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to achieve the requirement that my TextField can only accept 10 digits, and I have used 'rememberSaveable' so that when the user navigates to another screen and then comes back to this screen, the digits entered in TextField isn't lost.

I have used rememberSaveable like:

var query by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }

Then I used it in my TextField as:

```
            val maxChar = 10

            TextField(
                    value = query,
                    onValueChange = {
                        if (it.text.length <= maxChar) query = it
                    },
                label = {
                    Text(
                        "Name as on PAN Card",
                        color = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green),
                        fontSize = with(LocalDensity.current) { dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._12ssp).toSp() },
                        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.poppins_regular)),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Left

                    )
                },
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType =KeyboardType.Number),


                    textStyle = TextStyle(
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green),
                    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.poppins_regular)),

                    fontSize = with(LocalDensity.current) { dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._12ssp).toSp() }
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                        .drawBehind {
                            val strokeWidth = indicatorWidth.value * density
                            val y = size.height - strokeWidth / 2
                            drawLine(
                                    indicatorColor,
                                    Offset(TextFieldPadding.toPx(), y),
                                    Offset(size.width - TextFieldPadding.toPx(), y),
                                    strokeWidth
                            )
                        }
                        .constrainAs(name) {
                            bottom.linkTo(glNameBottom)
                            start.linkTo(glLeft)
                            end.linkTo(glRight)
                            width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                        }
                        .height((mHeight.value / 10.5).dp),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                    cursorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green),
                    focusedIndicatorColor = Transparent,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = Transparent,
                    disabledIndicatorColor = Transparent
                )
            )
```

But on using the above code I'm getting the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MutableState containing TextFieldValue(text='', selection=TextRange(0, 0), composition=null) cannot be saved using the current SaveableStateRegistry. The default implementation only supports types which can be stored inside the Bundle. Please consider implementing a custom Saver for this class and pass it as a stateSaver parameter to rememberSaveable().
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 38):

As suggested on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/package-summary#BasicTextField(androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextFieldValue,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush,kotlin.Function1)) for the `BasicTextField`, you can simply use the `TextFieldValue.Saver`:

```kotlin
var query by rememberSaveable(stateSaver = TextFieldValue.Saver) { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
```

Comment: If you see your `rememberSaveable()` arguments all squiggly red make sure that you use `stateSaver` as the parameter name. There are actually two `rememberSaveable()` functions - in the other one the parameter is called `saver` and it doesn't accept `mutableStateOf()` in the init block.

Comment: that solutions doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It is because `rememberSaveable` does not support the storage of `TextFieldValue`. As per the docs, you can create a custom saver object, but a FAR better solution would be to simply store your value inside a viewmodel. That way, it will be remembered throughout configuration changes as well as navigation. Also, I don't think `rememberSaveable` offers state-save across navigation so when you return to the screen, the text will anyway be lost (you can try that by changing the initialisation to `var query by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }`)

Just create a viewmodel

```
class VM: ViewModel(){
 var query by mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(""))
 private set

 fun onQueryChange(newQuery: textFieldCount){
       if (newQuery.text.length <= maxChar) query = newQuery
 }
}
```

Yeah that oughta do it

Inside your class,

```
            val maxChar = 10

            TextField(
                    value = viewmodel.query,
                    onValueChange = viewmodel::onQueryChange,
                label = {
                    Text(
                        "Name as on PAN Card",
                        color = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green),
                        fontSize = with(LocalDensity.current) { dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._12ssp).toSp() },
                        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.poppins_regular)),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Left

                    )
                },
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType =KeyboardType.Number),


                    textStyle = TextStyle(
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green),
                    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.poppins_regular)),

                    fontSize = with(LocalDensity.current) { dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._12ssp).toSp() }
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                        .drawBehind {
                            val strokeWidth = indicatorWidth.value * density
                            val y = size.height - strokeWidth / 2
                            drawLine(
                                    indicatorColor,
                                    Offset(TextFieldPadding.toPx(), y),
                                    Offset(size.width - TextFieldPadding.toPx(), y),
                                    strokeWidth
                            )
                        }
                        .constrainAs(name) {
                            bottom.linkTo(glNameBottom)
                            start.linkTo(glLeft)
                            end.linkTo(glRight)
                            width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                        }
                        .height((mHeight.value / 10.5).dp),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                    cursorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green),
                    focusedIndicatorColor = Transparent,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = Transparent,
                    disabledIndicatorColor = Transparent
                )
            )
```

Comment: I hope you know how to initialise a viewmodel. Referrnce the docs for a proper way. Roughly, you may initialise it as ```val viewmodel by viewmodels<VM>```, but you should consider creating a factory for it. It's a copy-paste business just referrnce the docs for it

Comment: I am getting an error in ViewModel, it says "composable invocations can only happen from the context of a composable", regarding rememberSaveable.

Comment: You are NOT supposed to use ```rememberSaveable``` inside the viewmodel. The very point of the viewmodel is to remember those values through activities and recompositions. Just copy the code above in my answer.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry. I copy-pasted your initialisation of ```query```. I'll just edit it out, thanks.